# Java - selection what to draw on canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, drawing

what I want to achieve is two buttons that enable the user choose the color ( black or red ) and then, depends on the color, draw red or black shape, e.g. rectangle on canvas.
I have a problem with relating MouseListeners connected with buttons to setting color of the graphics in Canvas class. Where should I define the color?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

class Can extends Canvas{
    int x,y;
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Can(){
            super();
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent k){
                    x = k.getX();
                    y = k.getY();
                    points.add(new Point(x,y));
                    repaint();
                }
        });   
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        int x2, y2;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(Color.black); //here is only black
        for(Point p:points)
        {
            x2=(int)p.getX();
            y2=(int)p.getY();
            g2.fillRect(x2, y2, 10, 5);

        }
    }
}
class Win extends JFrame{
    Win(String name){
        super(name);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p1.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        CheckboxGroup cg = new CheckboxGroup();
        Checkbox red = new Checkbox("red", cg, true);
        Checkbox black = new Checkbox("black", cg, false);
        p1.add(red);
        p1.add(black);
        add(p1);

        Can k = new Can();
        add(k);

        red.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

                System.out.println("Mouse click on red");    
            }     
        });

        black.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

                System.out.println("Mouse click on black");
            }     
        });

        setSize(600, 400);

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}

public class ItM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Win o = new Win("that's the window");

        o.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `paint()` check the state of the checkboxes. Then choose the color based on which one is selected.

Comment: Ok, but how should I check it? Is the state of the checkbox visible in Canvas class?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are using the `Swing` tag so your application should be using Swing components, not AWT components. Swing components start with "J", except for Canvas, where the Swing component is `JPanel`. You should then be overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method, not paint().

If you want to paint objects with different color then you have two options:

1. Paint directly to a BufferedImage. The then shape will be painted with the currently selected color
2. Paint from an ArrayList of object that contain  information about the shape to be painted, including the size/location/color

For working examples of both approaches check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).